# Is there a way to smoothly increase the density of points in a volume using the 'Distribute points in volume' node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

When you increase the density, the points jump about as if each new amount is a new seed. I'm looking for a way to do this so the volume is populated smoothly and controllably.

In ye olde Softimage XSI you could simply animate the emission rate on a volume emitting particles, but emission rate is un keyable in Blender, it seems.

Any help greatly appreciated. (Relative noob in Geo nodes)
Using 3.4.1

Thanks!

Comment: Ahh .. ye olde Softimage, of famed elegance and grace, long since swallowed by the gnarlèd dragon..

Comment: @RobinBetts The greatest tragedy of our time :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can generate maximum amount initially, and then choose from them only the desired amount.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh wow thanks! So how are you animating this - with the scene time?

Comment: Also, I'm trying to instance random objects from a collection. presumably I should replace your Separate Geometry node with an instance on points node?

Comment: @benz: pls click on the checkmark left of ugorek's answer, if it helped you. Thx.